# Можно ли использовать qt creator бесплатно?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtcreator

Делал свой проект в vs 2022 с расширением для qt. Все нормально было, потом перестали .ui файлы открываться. Ну, я попытался открыть qt designer, а там пишет что, мол, лицензии нет у меня. Приложение для себя пишу, т.е. не в коммерческих целях. Могу ли я бесплатно получить эту лицензию? Или в любом случае покупать ее надо / кряк качать?

Живу в России если что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно смотреть лицензии.
Основная часть `Qt` поставляется под двойной лицензией.
Одна из них `LGPL`

То есть Вы можете использовать `Qt` при соблюдении `LGPL`

`Qt Creator` как `IDE` можно скачать с [github](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/releases)

Comment: ну, допустим я ее соблюдаю. Как мне сделать так, чтоб у меня лицензию не просили?

Comment: @questions.Bloody.cpp Используйте версию с открытым исходным кодом

Comment: Там онлайн и офлайн установщики. По весу видно. Логин пароль просит. Логиниться нужно через впн